# Read txt file each second from PHP page

Tags: php

I have a webpage.....
I need to read a file each second (only 50 lines): /var/log/message     (CENTOS 6.5).
I tried with this but does not work

```
<?PHP

  $file_handle = fopen("error.txt", "rb");

     while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

  $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
  $parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);

print $parts[0] . "   <BR>";

}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your best shot to get this to work is by using [Cron](http://crontab.org/) to fire this certain script each minute.

If you want it to happen only when a user is accessing the page, you might want to do it by a javascript in the client that calls this php script each 60 seconds.

Comment: The question remains, do you want this to be done while a page is loaded or just in intervals of one secs regardless of someone having the page open or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option (performance wise) will be to use javascript (jquery) on the webpage with an appropriate PHP function
for example
add to webpage:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>//include jquery
    <script>
     function readErrorFile(){ // the function will load the contents of the php file to the errorDiv
        $('#errorDiv').load('pathToPhpFile.php');
      }
     $(function() { ///will load the function on page ready
         setTimeout(readErrorFile(), 50000); //set timeout
     });
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
<div id="errorDiv"></div>
</body>
```

on the php side:

```
echo file_get_contents('path_to_error_file.txt'); //format the output any way you want
```

Comment: echo file_get_contents('/var/log/iptables.log'); result nothing

Comment: Check for file premissions of iptables log